# How to generate Django template as MS word?

Tags: django, ms-word

Is there a way to build a Django template or make it like Microsoft word by making the Django template have tools and the ability to write word documents from a website instead?

if we supposed that there is a domain name called: example.com

so, when I open that website for **example.com/word-doc/** it will open a blank page and some tools from Microsoft Word to write in.

Is there any package or API to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for a kind of "wysiwyg" editor for client side (this part has nothing do with Django). The closest thing I could found is [this one](https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-word-processor), however it comes with a price tag.

In Django-side you'll (probably) simply store the data given by editor (client). The editor will then be able to parse it for update/read purposes.